# Why does Bitmap.FromFile() return an object of type Image

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

This is a really simple question that has always bothered me because almost everytime I write the code I am tripped up but this line.

```
Bitmap image = Bitmap.FromFile("c:\img.jpg");
```

I always intuitively assume that an object returned from a static method named `FromFile`  in class `X` would be of type `X`.

I realize that obviously I can cast back to `Bitmap` if I want and I'm sure I'm missing something but as per the title why does `Bitmap.FromFile(Path)` return an Image instead of a `Bitmap`? Was this just a poorly thought out design or is there a more fundamental reason to return the parent class in this instance?

Comment: Well, you should be tripped up by it.  The compile error hopefully reminds you to use the Bitmap constructor instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`FromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx) is a static method on `Image`, which is the base type of `Bitmap`. You can access the static method through Bitmap, even though you are really calling `Image.FromFile`. I suppose Bitmap could hide (or shadow) the FromFile on Image with its own that returned a Bitmap, but for whatever reason it wasn't done that way.

There are other child types of `Image`, such as [`Metafile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.metafile(v=vs.110).aspx) (images with a .wmf extension). The purpose here is to achieve a polymorphic behavior - you can use FromFile to load an image and not care what underlying implementation is used to work with an image.

Comment: Of course, completely missed that it was a static on the parent. Thanks very much for the answer!